# Python: how to reshape a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that contains information of different cities, such as:

```
print(df)

     ID     City    Var             Year    Value
0   AT001   Vienna  CO2_PC          2000    12.77
1   AT001   Vienna  CO2_PC          2005    15.42
2   AT001   Vienna  CO2_PC          2008    14.23
3   AT001   Vienna  AIR_POLLUTION   2002    24.09
4   AT001   Vienna  AIR_POLLUTION   2005    21.03
5   AT001   Vienna  AIR_POLLUTION   2008    16.77
```

For each `City` I would like to have to extract the value of the average of each variables for the different `Year` and have a dataframe like the following:

```
print(df1)

     ID      City     CO2_PC    AIR_POLLUTION
0   AT001   Vienna    13.81         20.66
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way:

```
df2 = df.groupby(['ID', 'City', 'Var'])['Value'].mean().reset_index()

df2 = pd.pivot_table(df2, index=['ID', 'City'], columns=['Var']).reset_index()

df2.columns = [' '.join(col).strip() for col in df2.columns.values]
```

**Result**

```
      ID    City  Value AIR_POLLUTION  Value CO2_PC
0  AT001  Vienna                20.63         14.14
```

**Explanation**

- Group  by relevant factors and calculate mean.
- Pivot and rename columns, to align 'Value' headings as required.